# NavController is not available before onCreate() thrown inside onCreate

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I started getting this weird crash in Crashlytics that seems to point out that I'm utilizing the `navController` before `onCreate()` while pointing at a block of code inside that same `onCreate()` method!

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
NavController is not available before onCreate()
```

The crash is happening in my initial Fragment, well after everything gets set up inside the single Activity. Not sure what the problem might be or how to solve!

### EDIT:

Here's where the crash logs points too, on the `startLocationPermissionFlow()` call

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!requireContext().isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
            // Location permission is needed to get SSID info from WifiManager
            // see FragmentExtension.isConnected
            startLocationPermissionFlow()
        }
    }
```

Which looks like this

```
private fun startLocationPermissionFlow() {
        findNavController().navigate(
            WelcomeFragmentDirections.actionGlobalInterstitialFragment(
                type = InterstitialFragment.PermissionType.LOCATION
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Are you using the latest Navigation 2.3.2? There are fixes in that release for exactly this.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm not on the latests version, no. But since I haven't been able to reproduce this error, part of my attempt to mitigate it was/is to update to the latests release. Thanks

Comment: I added some code @SamChen

Comment: Here is the link to what @ianhanniballake is talking about.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171605525